# Marketing Cloud - Change Field Size in UI Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ui

While creating or editing a record in a Data Extension, the fields in Marketing Cloud UI (Contact Builder) are too small. I have some fields where I only need to put some four char code and they are bigger than I need, and some fields that are descriptive and are too small.

Is possible to change those fields display size in a Data Extension?

[image: Data Extension]

Comment: Hi @Leto, there is no configuration option to widen/extend the DE columns, however, you can try using a big screen with wider resolution to show more content.

Comment: there is KI that is related to this: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003UZMQA2&title=contact-builder-data-extension-on-editing-records-of-data-extension-the-size-of-columns-become-too-small-with-a-large-number-of-column-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not much customization (if any) that you can adjust in the Marketing Cloud user interface.

Alternatively you can create the import file as a CSV file and [Import Data into a Marketing Cloud Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_import_data_extension_classic.htm&type=5). That way you can see the entire length of the field value in the CSV file before importing.